# How to persist data in a Quartz.net job Trigger between executions?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

There are a couple SO articles about this, but only one [directly addresses this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836211/jobdata-is-not-persisted-after-each-execution-in-quartz-net).  However, the solution doesn't make sense for me.  I'm using a straight string.

**UPDATE:**

This:

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
public class BackgroundTaskTester : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Value Is: " + context.Trigger.JobDataMap["field1"] as string);
        context.Trigger.JobDataMap["field1"] = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Outputs This:

```
Value Is: 
Value Is: 
Value Is: 
Value Is: 
Value Is: 
Value Is: 
Value Is:
```

But this:

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
public class BackgroundTaskTester : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Value Is: " + context.JobDetail.JobDataMap["field1"] as string);
        context.JobDetail.JobDataMap["field1"] = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Outputs This:

```
Value Is: 10/6/2014 9:26:23 AM -05:00
Value Is: 10/6/2014 9:26:28 AM -05:00
Value Is: 10/6/2014 9:26:33 AM -05:00
```

However, I want to store things in the **Trigger**.  How do I get the Trigger to persist?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a class:

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
public class BackgroundTaskNotification : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        <see below>
    }

}
```

The following code doesn't function as expected:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    string x = context.MergedJobDataMap["field1"];

    context.Put("field1", "test string");

    string y = context.MergedJobDataMap["field1"];

    // PROBLEM: x != y
}
```

I've tried `context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put()` and also `context.Trigger.JobDataMap.Put()`  None of them update MergedJobDataMap.

Maybe that's OK though.  There is a JobDataMap on the JobDetail object and the Trigger.  What I'm trying to do is this:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    string x = context.MergedJobDataMap["field1"];  //get last x

    <do something with x>

    context.Put("field1", x);  //save updated x

}
```

I'm trying to do something with x and have x persist between runs.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'll add that when I create the job, I actually put `field1` into the trigger's `JobDataMap`.  This is because I have a single Job, and multiple triggers.  I want the data to be stored at the tigger level.

Comment: Your first code snippet seems correct... you pull out the current value, set it to something different (I assume "test string" isn't the value you set outside of this class), and then you claim there's a problem because x != y.  That's the behavior I expect... that x and y are unequal since I changed it.

Comment: I updated the question.  Storing things in the JobDetail works if I do it the way you said, but fails in the trigger.

Answer (score 4):

### Original Answer

MergedDataMap is a combination of the TriggerDataMap and the JobDataMap (with trigger entries overriding job entries).  Updating this will do nothing, since it doesn't propagate changes back to the original JobDataMap or TriggerDataMap, and it's only JobDataMap that is re-persisted.

You want to set `context.JobDetail.JobDataMap["field1"]` in order for it to be persisted.

### Update 1 (based on question edit):

If you want to save to the Trigger datamap, you do have to do a little more work.

If you look in the `IJobExecutionContext` you are given in `Execute()`, you have an instance of the scheduler that started the job, and an instance of the trigger that started the job.  Combine with info here:

[Update Quart.NET Trigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger)

to update the trigger as part of the job execution.  Note that this updates the trigger *immediately*, not after the job run (as when Quartz manages your job data for you).

This can be adapted to work for the job's data map as well, and have the changes persisted immediately vs. automatically at the end of the job execution.

Comment: I updated the question. It didn't work for the Trigger.  It does work for the JobDetail.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I think the problem with that solution is that it is causing a reschedule of the entire job.  While that will certainly work, it's not really what I'm after.  I have a job with a lot of triggers and some could be firing right now and some could be imminent.   This would disrupt those.  Maybe this is a design gap in Quartz.

Comment: link in your answer is dead unfortunately.